# How to check if data exists in Mongo Db

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using NodeJs and MongoDb as a backend service I am getting data from frontend and checking if its available in database or not.Below is my code what I have done so far:

**PROBLEM:** It is always showing response `Res:0` even if data is available in database.

```
router.post('/checkOtp',(req,res) => {

      const data = {
          otp:req.body.otp  
      };

      MongoClient.connect(dburl,{useNewUrlParser:true,useUnifiedTopology:true},(err,client) => {

                if(err){
                    console.log("Error",err);
                }
                else{

                    const coll = client.db("Aamku_connect").collection("Otps");
                    coll.find({otp:data.otp}).toArray((err,result) => {

                        if(err){
                            console.log("Error",err);
                        }
                        else{
                            let max = result.length;                               
                            res.send("Res:"+max);
                        }
                    });
                }

         });

 });
```

**MongoDb Document structure is shown below**

```
  {
   "_id":{
     "$oid":"5e2550b0ccd7b80017112c33"
         },
     "otp":{
        "$numberInt":"6579"
           }
   }
```

Someone please let me know how do I finish Splash activity.Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Comment: `console.log` the value for `data.otp` and verify its value. Are you able to query the collection from the _mongo shell_ or Compass?

Comment: Have you made sure you are getting something in `data.otp` ?

Comment: `console.log` is returning the exact value I have passed.

Comment: @Ashish yes in `data.otp` i have passed 4 digit value and it is showing on doing `console.log` but unable to check in MongoDb.

Comment: can you post your mongo document as well?

Comment: also worth checking that in mongo it is in same data type. like if you have string then it is string or if you are sending integer then it is integer.

Comment: Please check the type of OTP. is it the same in DB and request.body?

Comment: @Ashish it is of Integer data type in database.

Comment: @Digvijay check typeof req.body.otp, if it is string convert it to a number before comparing.

Comment: @Raghu how can I convert String into a integer  for comparison

Comment: @Digvijay use Number(req.body.otp)

Comment: Before querying change it to number: `data.otp = +data.otp`

Answer (score 0):

For cleaner Code Use Promise

```
function getOtps (otp) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    const coll = client.db("Aamku_connect").collection("Otps");
          coll.find({otp:otp}).toArray((err,result) => {
            if (err) {
              // Reject the Promise with an error
               reject(err)
            } else{
               resolve(result.length);
             }
            });
  })
}
```

Use it like

```
  MongoClient.connect(dburl,{useNewUrlParser:true,useUnifiedTopology:true},(err,client) => {
            if(err){
                console.log("Error",err);
            }
            else{
              getOtps(data.otp).then( length => res.send("Res:"+length); ).catch(err=>console.log(err))
            }

     });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this as shown in below code . \

```
var Db = require('mongodb').Db,
MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
Server = require('mongodb').Server,
router.post('/checkOtp',(req,res) => {

  const data = {
  otp:req.body.otp  
  };


  var db = new Db('Aamku_connect', new Server('localhost', 27017));
  // Establish connection to db
  db.open(function(err, db) {
      // Get a collection
      db.collection('Otps', function(err, collection) {
        //Checking the document that exist or not .        
        collection.find({{otp:data.otp}}, function(err, item) {
          console.log(item);
          db.close();
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make nested find query to match OTP. So just mofdify your query find({otp:data.otp}) to find({'otp.$numberInt':data.otp})

```
router.post('/checkOtp',(req,res) => {

  const data = {
      otp:req.body.otp  
  };

  MongoClient.connect(dburl,{useNewUrlParser:true,useUnifiedTopology:true},(err,client) => {

            if(err){
                console.log("Error",err);
            }
            else{

                const coll = client.db("Aamku_connect").collection("Otps");
                coll.find({'otp.$numberInt':data.otp}).toArray((err,result) => {
                    if(err){
                        console.log("Error",err);
                    }
                    else{
                        let max = result.length;                               
                        res.send("Res:"+max);
                    }
                });
            }

     });

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the code you want:

just import `mongoClient` from the official mongoDB nodejs driver like this:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
```

then define your address to connect:

```
const mongo_dataBase = new MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/your_database_name', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
```

then check the connection with:

```
// checking connection
mongo_dataBase
    .connect()
    .then(
        (mongo_dataBase) => mongo_dataBase.db().admin().listDatabases(),
        // resolving the list of databases
    )
    .then((dbs) => {
        const database = dbs.databases.find((element) => element.name === 'your_database_name');

        if (database) {
            console.log(`database -> (${database.name}) found`);
        } else {
            console.log('DB not found');
        }
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error))
    .finally(() => mongo_dataBase.close()); // Closing connection
```